# Is there a single word descriptor for a plan, document, or process that is formalized only after its execution?

Tags: single-word-requests

Examples:

After much pressure from their constituents, the committee finally published their [blank] plan on how they lowered taxes.

The comedy troupe had a [blank] rehearsal after the comedy show.

Six months after construction completed, critics panned the architect's [blank] design.

I was thinking **post-iterative**, but that may imply a follow up is expected whereas the execution should imply finality. I was also thinking **posthumous** but it seems incorrect to use it outside the context of death.

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***retrospective***:

> **1a(1):** of, relating to, or given to *retrospection*
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrospective)</sub>

And *retrospection* is:

> : the act or process or an instance of surveying the past
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrospection)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The Latin phrase *post hoc* is used in English as if it were a single word. Its meaning is

> occurring or done after the event, especially with reference to the fallacious assumption that the occurrence in question has a logical relationship with the event it follows.

[source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/post_hoc)]

Comment: Maybe *ex post facto*?